# How to make the lookup fields on my custom DispForm.aspx not clickable?

Tags: custom-form

I have created for "ListA" a new custom DispForm.aspx and name it CustomDispForm.aspx. In this custom form I have 1 lookup field like this:

```
<div id="Artikelnaam"><xsl:value-of select="@Artikelen" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></div>
```

It is working, but the lookup field is rendered as a hyper link. Is it possible to remove the hyperlink or change the url to #?

This is the html which is rendered. I can see it when I set disable-output-escaping="no".

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Artikelen" disable-output-escaping="no"/>


<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('https://myCompany.nl/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={05135bcf-13d8-449f-b541-b2d31fd8e6a8}&ID=24&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); 
return false;" href="https://myCompany.nl/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={05135bcf-13d8-449f-b541-b2d31fd8e6a8}&ID=24&RootFolder=*">Bord &#39;besmetgebied&#39;</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do an `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@YourField, ';#')" />` I believe. You might need to adjust the ;# part but as I recall, the lookup field value is returned like 1;#Name.

So in you example (had to edit your post to see it) it would be like:

```
<div id="Artikelnaam"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Artikelen, ';#')" /></div>
```

Edit: If that is the returned value, then it'll need to be adjusted to something like this to get the anchor value:
`<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@Artikelen, '*&quot;&gt;'), '&lt;/a&gt;')" />`

Comment: No it dont work. See my update for the a href which is created underwater. your code gives me an empty div.

Comment: updated answer, you might need to play with the escaped characters, I did it off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric, this works. Can you please explain the substring before and substring after?

Comment: They are what the are, string functions that return a string before or after a set of characters. So this is saying from the string @Artikelen, give me everything after *">. From that string give me everything before </a>. The result is the anchor tag value.